# ValueError: in case of LSTM with `stateful=True`

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I tried to use LSTM network with `stateful=True` as follows:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

raw = np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(1024)/float(1024/2))
data = pd.DataFrame(raw)

window_size = 3
data_s = data.copy()
for i in range(window_size):
    data = pd.concat([data, data_s.shift(-(i+1))], axis = 1)   
data.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)

print (data)
ds = data.values

n_rows = ds.shape[0]
ts = int(n_rows * 0.8)

train_data = ds[:ts,:]
test_data = ds[ts:,:]

train_X = train_data[:,:-1]
train_y = train_data[:,-1]
test_X = test_data[:,:-1]
test_y = test_data[:,-1]

print (train_X.shape)
print (train_y.shape)
print (test_X.shape)
print (test_y.shape)
```

(816, 3)
(816,)
(205, 3)
(205,)

```
batch_size = 3
n_feats = 1

train_X = train_X.reshape(train_X.shape[0], batch_size, n_feats)
test_X = test_X.reshape(test_X.shape[0], batch_size, n_feats)
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape)

regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 64, batch_input_shape=(train_X.shape[0], batch_size, n_feats),
                   activation = 'sigmoid',  
                   stateful=True, return_sequences=True))

regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))

regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

resetCallback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_begin=lambda epoch,logs: regressor.reset_states())

regressor.fit(train_X, train_y, batch_size=7, epochs = 1, callbacks=[resetCallback])

previous_inputs = test_X                                    
regressor.reset_states()

previous_predictions = regressor.predict(previous_inputs).reshape(-1)
test_y = test_y.reshape(-1)
plt.plot(test_y, color = 'blue')
plt.plot(previous_predictions, color = 'red')
plt.show()
```

However, I got:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (816, 1)
```

PS this code has been adapted from https://github.com/danmoller/TestRepo/blob/master/testing%20the%20blog%20code%20-%20train%20and%20pred.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two minor bugs:

Here you have

```
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 64, batch_input_shape=(train_X.shape[0], batch_size, n_feats),
               activation = 'sigmoid',
               stateful=True, return_sequences=True))
```

This LSTM will return a 3D vector, but your y is 2D which throws a valuerror. You can fix this with `return_sequences=False`. I'm not sure why you initially had `train_X.shape[0]` inside of your `batch_input`, the number of samples in your entire set shouldn't affect the size of each batch.

```
    regressor.add(LSTM(units = 64, batch_input_shape=(1, batch_size, n_feats),
               activation = 'sigmoid',
               stateful=True, return_sequences=False))
```

After this you have

```
regressor.fit(train_X, train_y, batch_size=7, epochs = 1, callbacks=[resetCallback])
```

In a stateful network you can only put in a number of inputs that divides the batch size. Since 7 doesn't divide 816 we change this to 1:

```
regressor.fit(train_X, train_y, batch_size=1, epochs = 1, callbacks=[resetCallback])
```

The same goes in your predict. You must specify `batch_size=1`:

```
previous_predictions = regressor.predict(previous_inputs, batch_size=1).reshape(-1)
```

Comment: his y had 3 dims your has 2. to reduce dimensions i have `return_sequences=False`. He doesn't have to do that because his in and out are the same dim

Comment: You could but what about this: you add another LSTM layer with return_sequences=True and have the last one with it false to reduce to 2

Comment: yeah. I think you'd also want the output to be 2D so you only have to predict the next price instead of more features

Comment: I don't think it would affect your model's performance much if at all

Comment: Remember the most important part for making neural networks is choosing the data that you put in and preprocessing that data. Regardless of the model, if garbage goes in garbage goes out.

Comment: Hi, could you answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50078485/lstm-for-future-predictions